# Typescript compiler, how to get an exported symbol by name?

Tags: typescript-compiler-api

What is the best way to get the symbol for an export by name?

Bellow is functional code. However, it does seems a bit fragile as I can't get the 'symbol' from 'sourceFile' without ignoring the type system.

```js
  const sourceFile = tsprogram.getSourceFile('foo_file.ts');
  const fileSymbol = (sourceFile as any).symbol as ts.Symbol; // anything better her? 
  const  export = fileSymbol.exports.get('FooComponent');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the type checker:

```
const fileSymbol = tsprogram.getTypeChecker().getSymbolAtLocation(sourceFile);
const fooComponentSymbol = fileSymbol?.exports.get('FooComponent');
```

Note that `fileSymbol` will be undefined when there are no file exports.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Are there any good sources where to learn how the typescript compiler api works?

Comment: Not really :( Basically just https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Architectural-Overview -- I've mostly tried to figure it out by searching through it's declaration file: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/typescript.d.ts

Comment: Nice! One follow up question, once you have a reference to fooComponentSymbol. What happens when you have ```function Foo(){} .   export default Foo``` how do you navigate from the export to the actual function. Example I want the type for the function and doing typeChecker.getTypeOfSymbolAtLocation(fooComponentSymbol, fooComponentSymbol.valueDeclaration); won't work in this case.

Comment: @JoseCh. probably best to ask a new question so others can benefit from it being easier to find. I'm heading out right now, but will answer it tomorrow in case nobody else has.

Comment: sounds good. Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58886590/typescript-compiler-how-to-navigate-to-the-definition-of-a-symbol thanks!