# How can I use the TS Compiler API to find where a variable was defined in another file

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

given:

```
// foo.ts
import { bar } from "./bar"

// bar.ts
export const bar = 3;
```

If I have a `ts.Symbol` for the `bar` in "foo.ts", how can I get to the `bar` in "bar.ts"?

Ideally, TS compiler API would expose a definition-use chain that I can traverse to find the definition. I don't think it does, though.

So now I'm trying to:

- use the module specifier "./bar.ts" and the current `ts.SourceFile` to get a `ts.ResolvedModule` object representing "bar.ts", which contains the full file path.
- Do `ts.SourceFile(fullFilePath)` to get a `ts.SourceFile` for "bar.ts"
- Do `checker.getExportsOfModule(symbolForBarDotTs)` to get the exports from "bar.ts" and find the one with a matching name.

The tricky part seems to be resolving the module from the module specifier. I don't want to write the logic for module resolution from scratch because the algorithm is complex and depends on the interaction of at least six compiler options. Two parts of the TS Compiler API seemed promising:

- `host.resolveModuleNames`, which is unfortunately only available if the host has implemented it, and the default compiler host does not implement it.
- use `(program.getSourceFile(pathToFoo) as any).resolvedModules`. The `resolvedModules` property seems to have exactly what I'm looking for, but is not part of the public API.

Is there a better way? I'm hoping to:

- stop using non-private API
- stop doing so much work that the compiler already knows how to do

  "bar.ts"

In this case, it is easy to see that "./bar" refers to the adjacent source file on the file system with a matching name, but when someone uses "paths" or "node_modules" or "@types", etc. then module resolution is non-trivial.

### Update

For the general question of:

> If I have a `ts.Symbol` for the `bar` in "foo.ts", how can I get to the `bar` in "bar.ts"?

[@DavidSherret's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59847032/2482570) will work most of the time.

However, it doesn't do what I'm looking for in the following case:

```
// foo.ts
import { bar } from "./bar"

// bar.ts
export { bar } from "./baz"

// baz.ts
export const bar = 3;
```

TypeChecker#getAliasedSymbol says that `baz` in "foo.ts" points to `bar` in "baz.ts", skipping "bar.ts" entirely. This worn't work for my purposes, because I'm trying to find out, given a set of entrypoints, which parts of .d.ts files are no longer needed, and remove the unneeded parts. In this case it would be a bad idea to remove "bar.ts".

Comment: You ask such easy questions :P. For compiler API stuff isn't GH is a better venue?

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure I'd call this a Feature Request unless someone confirms that there is no public API for what I'm trying to achieve, then I could open an issue.

Comment: You can open an issue with a question on GitHub, if I'm not mistaken. @TitianCernicova-Dragomir is one of the contributors...

Comment: @HereticMonkey  Max Heiber is also a contributor :)

Comment: opened an issue: thanks for your feedback and suggestions https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36351

Comment: will try `ts.resolveModuleName` per recommendation on this issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The named import's symbol will have an associated "aliased symbol", which represents the declaration. So to get the variable declaration's symbol you can use the `TypeChecker#getAliasedSymbol` method, then from that get the declaration.

For example:

```
const barNamedImportSymbol = typeChecker.getSymbolAtLocation(barNamedImport.name)!;
const barSymbol = typeChecker.getAliasedSymbol(barNamedImportSymbol);
const barDeclaration = barSymbol.declarations[0] as ts.VariableDeclaration;

console.log(barDeclaration.getText(barFile)); // outputs `bar = 3`
```

The import declaration's named import has a separate symbol because that's the symbol specific to the "foo.ts" file.

**Update: Getting symbol of file referenced in module specifier**

To get the symbol of a file referenced in an import or export declarations module specifier, you can get the symbol of the module specifier node:

```
const otherFileSymbol = typeChecker.getSymbolAtLocation(importDeclaration.moduleSpecifier)!;
```

From there, you can check its exports for a certain name:

```
const barSymbol = otherFileSymbol.exports!.get(ts.escapeLeadingUnderscores("bar"))!;
// outputs: export { bar } from "./baz"; in second example above
console.log(barSymbol.declarations[0].parent.parent.getText());
```

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't 100% solve my problem, though. I asked how to get to "bar" in `import { bar } from "./bar"` The method in this answer won't always work, becase getAliasedSymbol skips in-between files. That is, if `foo.ts` is doing `export { bar } from "./baz"` then the aliased symbol will live in baz.ts, not in bar.ts. This is a problem because I'm doing dead code elimination and need to mark bar.ts as live in this case. Either that, or rewrite the module specifier, but that would also require knowing about module resolution.

Comment: @MaxHeiber could you update your question with an example showing what you mean? I was only answering: "If I have a ts.Symbol for the bar in "foo.ts", how can I get to the bar in "bar.ts"?" There are a lot of different scenarios to handle... for example [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58892917/188246).

Comment: Very sorry for my delay! I've updated my answer with what I think you're looking for.

Comment: thanks @davidSherret. I picked your answer as the correct one, but went with using ts.resolveModuleName because it was a smaller change to the code - either solution seems to work though.

Comment: @MaxHeiber I think using `ts.resolveModuleName` will not work in scenarios that the program host implements its own module resolution. See [`ProgramHost#resolveModuleNames`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/3b919e2ab1ba5546141e6677b44211de6f7e8d11/lib/typescript.d.ts#L4719). I believe `ts.resolveModuleNames` is the default module resolution that the program uses if `ProgramHost#resolveModuleNames` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

For resolving module names, use `ts.resolveModuleName`, [as recommended on this TS issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36351#issuecomment-577181359).

Here is the signature, from `typescript.d.ts`:

```
resolveModuleNames?(moduleNames: string[], containingFile: string, reusedNames: string[] | undefined, redirectedReference: ResolvedProjectReference | undefined, options: CompilerOptions): (ResolvedModule | undefined)[];
```

Alternatively, for going directly to the original definition of a symbol, see [@DavidSherret's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59847032/2482570)