# How can I use the TypeScript Compiler API to find where an ambient module declaration is defined?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

If something is defined in an ambient module declaration in another file:

```
declare module "@foo" {
    export default function func(): number;
}
```

and use the module:

```
import func from "@foo";
```

How can I use the TS Compiler API to find out where `func` is defined?

Normally, for figuring out where imports come from, I use `ts.resolveModuleName`, but it always returns `undefined` in this case.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible by following the symbols to the declaration.

1. Get the `func` identifier node.
2. Get its symbol, which will be local to the current file.
3. Get the aliased symbol of that symbol, which will be the symbol of the declaration.
4. Get that aliased symbol's declaration, which will be the function declaration.

Here's a contained example:

```
// setup
import { createProjectSync, ts } from "@ts-morph/bootstrap";

const project = createProjectSync();
project.createSourceFile("foo.d.ts", `declare module "@foo" { export default function func(): number; }`);
const sourceFile = project.createSourceFile("file.ts", `import func from "@foo";`);
const typeChecker = project.createProgram().getTypeChecker();

// get the "func" identifier in the import declaration
const importDec = sourceFile.statements[0] as ts.ImportDeclaration;
const funcIdent = importDec.importClause!.name!;

// follow the symbols to the function declaration
const funcImportSymbol = typeChecker.getSymbolAtLocation(funcIdent)!;
const funcDecSymbol = typeChecker.getAliasedSymbol(funcImportSymbol);
const funcDec = funcDecSymbol.getDeclarations()![0];

console.log(funcDec.getText());
```

Also, for getting the source file referenced in a module specifier, I still recommend getting the module specifier's symbol instead of using `ts.resolveModuleName` as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59847032/188246).

Comment: Thanks for this detailed and careful answer! This will work 90% of the time. However, due to the same reason as [in the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838013/how-can-i-use-the-ts-compiler-api-to-find-where-a-variable-was-defined-in-anothe/59847032#comment105833148_59847032) we can't skip intermediary symbols: we want to follow the module graph and gather all the files referenced.

Comment: I think getting the symbol of the module specifier should work ok in this scenario? I don't think there will be intermediary symbols in this case.

Comment: Good idea! I'll try it.

Comment: The module specifier is a string literal, and doesn't have a symbol. The importClause name has a symbol, but getAliasedSymbol(importClauseSymbol) returns `unknown`

Comment: @MaxHeiber use `typeChecker.getSymbolAtLocation(importDec.moduleSpecifier)`

Comment: Also, the example above does not return `unknown` when getting the import clause's name's symbol. Perhaps update the question to show this behaviour?